# Aborting job in pentaho without error message in log

Tags: pentaho, pdi

A bit of context. We have a parent job, which calls a transformation which eventually retrieves and processes an XML file from a service, and then determines if there is a "next link" in the xml and then retrieves this next link, puts it in a parameter and then ends the transformation. This all works fine.

[image][image]

In the parent job itself we call the transformation, then in the next step we evaluate the link variable. if it is empty, we abort the job, else we continue to succes. Then we put the job via start on an infinite repeat until the link is empty and the job is aborted.

Also works fine.

The only issue we have is that the "abort job" will keep triggering a line in the logging of the job, which mentions it as an error (and thus triggering our monitoring software). While in reality it is not really an error. Its just an abortion of the infinite loop since a condition is met (in this case no further links).

[image]

I can rename the abort job step, and give it a descriptive message, but it will keep mentioning it as error in the logging. Is there a way to circumvent this? Seems a bit weird this is fixed in the message since not all aborts have to be errors.

Answer (score -1):

So that’s not an error, but a warning or an alert. Just use a Write to log step to log that line you need, and end the job with a success step and not an abort.

Comment: not an option, since as i mentioned I am are running a repeat start step, which will not be interrupted with a succes step. It will just reitterate again then. You need an abort as mentioned in the question to interupt the loop. Or I must be missing something on this level....

Comment: In which case you should do the iteration at parent job level. The parent calls the child many times, the child decides where to go based on results. 

Alternatively, you can have a loop in a job with an evaluation step to decide how to move forward.

Comment: Hi, I might be misunderstanding your first solution. We don't know how often the transformation calling the api and processing the results need to be repeated for followup links. This can be none or hundreds of times. So we can't set a fixed number in the parent job. This means that if we set the parent job to unlimited looping, we still need to abort it. Even if we let the child decide to go somewhere else. Alternatively if we let the child call itself if a new link is found, then in Pentaho it runs veeery quickly out of memory.

Comment: "Alternatively, you can have a loop in a job with an evaluation step to decide how to move forward."

Your second solution (loop within job itself) might work. I was always advised against this because of a risk of stalling, but in this case it might work. I will try this one.

Comment: The loop is done at the job level,  not transformation level. Loops in transformations is an anti-pattern. But in a job it’s fine, just make sure to add an exit condition that gets verified at some point. There are numerous examples on iteratively making api calls until you run out of records and the abort is never necessary. Parent job: calls transformation until work is done. Transformation: calls api, checks if work is done and sets a variable to signal that to the parent.

Comment: if you can put the "Alternatively, you can have a loop in a job with an evaluation step to decide how to move forward." in a seperate answer, or edit your answer to it, then i can approve it.